# Last word wrapped to another line after changing the font

Tags: css, fonts, css-float, word-wrap

This is really driving me mad.

This is how the site used to be before changing the font:

[image]

And this is how it became after changing the font, the new font is [Droid Arabic Kufi from here.](http://www.google.com/fonts/earlyaccess)

[image]

You see, before changing the font, the words "مالك اللحام" we on the same line, while after changing the font the last word went to a separate line.

This is happening although I'm not making any restrictions on the width, it wraps only the last word no matter how many words there are, see here:

[image]

Please not that I'm not using `word-warp`, `word-break`, `width` or anything I know that might reasonably cause this problem. The only thing that I could know to be causing the problem is, hold back, cascaded float values!

It's hard to explain it here, so please try inspecting [here in this link](http://mag.wikilogians.org/2013/09/30/%D8%A3%D9%87%D9%84%D8%A7-%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85/) and setting `float` to `none`. The problem will disappear for that element, but won't for a lot other elements which suffer the same problem and can't be solved the same way. Because setting `float:none;` will float these elements to the left, which is not what I want.

Any help will be much appreciated, I've been trying with this for hours without any success.

Comment: This is just a suggestion. But based on the structure of this div, I think that it would make sense to apply a horizontal unordered list, rather than a set of separate divs.

Comment: @KimGysen I'm using the [Sampression Lite theme](http://sampression.com/) so the HTML structure is not mine, but I'll try doing this although, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding

> white-space: nowrap

to elements containing the text (e.g. `.post-author`, `.cats` and `<time>`).

Comment: This appears to work for all problematic elements, thanks alot, I'll wait a while before accepting your answer :)

Comment: i was having the same problem with the same font, shockingly it was working perfectly with IE before this, now it works also in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The `a` in div `.author` isn't closed properly:

```
<a class="url fn n" href="..." title="شاهد جميع المقالات التي كتبها مالك اللحام">مالك اللحام</a>
```

Should read:

```
<a class="..." href="..." title="...">...</a>
```

`<"` should be `">`.

And you could use `&nbsp;`

```
This&nbsp;will&nbsp;not&nbsp;wrap!
```